# How can I get printf to display a calculation the computer performed earlier?

Tags: c

What I'm having trouble doing is figuring out how to make a simple calculator in which I input hours, `PRO_H`, `PRE_H`, etc, and then using fixed rates, `PRO_R`, `PRE_R`, etc, to calculate how much money was owed. I would just like the `printf()` function at the end to output the calculation the code will perform. I'm not sure if my format would work for the multiplication, though.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int PRO_R =100;
    int PRE_R =60;
    int PROD_R =40;

    int PRO_H =0;
    int PRE_H =0;
    int PROD_H =0;

// Do I need to declare these as intergers for calculations?

    int PRO_C =PRO_H * PRO_R;
    int PRE_C =PRE_H * PRE_R;
    int PROD_C =PROD_C * PRE_R;
    int TOT_C =PRO_C + PRE_C + PROD_C;

    printf("Enter Production Hours:\n");
    scanf("%d", &PRO_H);

    printf("Enter Pre-Production Hours:\n");
    scanf("%d", &PRE_H);

    printf("Enter Producer's Hours:\n");
    scanf("%d", &PROD_H);

// These are the calculations below in which I need to get outputted. So the I would like the total cost, PRO_C, to equal the PRO_H times the PRO_R. 

    PRO_C =(PRO_H * PRO_R);
    PRE_C =(PRE_H * PRE_R);
    PROD_C =(PROD_H * PROD_H);
    TOT_C =(PRO_C + PRE_C + PROD_C);

    printf("Production cost:");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Production cost: %d", TOT_C);`

Comment: [Some handy reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Using uppercase identifiers is not the way to intiminidate the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want something like this printed out? Is that right? You just do "%d" in the spot that you want to display your integer and outside the quotes you put a comma and the integer you wanted to print.

```
// These are the calculations below in which I need to get outputted. So the I would like the total cost, PRO_C, to equal the PRO_H times the PRO_R. 

PRO_C =(PRO_H * PRO_R);
PRE_C =(PRE_H * PRE_R);
PROD_C =(PROD_H * PROD_H);
TOT_C =(PRO_C + PRE_C + PROD_C);


printf("Production cost: %d", TOT_C);
```